# Tapestry 5.4 URL rewriting and SEO URLs

Tags: url-rewriting, seo, tapestry, friendly-url

i'm writing a web application in tapestry.
In my application i want to use friendly urls. Now i'm able to to render the url page like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/page/page-name
```

wat i want to do is to render URLs like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/page-name
```

All pages are stored on a Postgresql DB.
I'm currently using Tapestry 5.4-beta16 and i've already read the tapestry documentation:

http://tapestry.apache.org/url-rewriting.html

http://blog.tapestry5.de/index.php/2010/09/06/new-url-rewriting-api/

Now, this is the Class for list all pages stored on the DB (Only for test)

```
public class Pages {

  @Inject
  private Session session;

  @Property
  List<it.garuti.tapestrycms.entities.Pagine> pagine;

  @Property
  private it.garuti.tapestrycms.entities.Pagine pagina;


  void setupRender() {

      pagine = session.createCriteria(it.garuti.tapestrycms.entities.Pagine.class).list();

  }

}
```

And this is the class for show the page content:

```
public class Page {

@Property
private Page page;

@Inject
private Logger logger;

@Inject
private Session session;

@Inject
Request request;


@InjectPage
Index index;

@Property
private String slug;



 void onActivate(String slug) {

    this.slug = slug;

}

Object onActivate() {
    if (session.createCriteria(Pagine.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("slug", slug)).uniqueResult() == null)
        return     new HttpError(404, "Resource not found");
    return null;
}

String onPassivate() {
    return slug;
}

void setupRender() {
    page = (Pages) session.createCriteria(Pages.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("slug", slug)).uniqueResult();

}
}
```

And finally the Entity for Pages:

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "pages", schema = "public")
public class Pages implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "pagine_seq")
@SequenceGenerator( name= "pagine_seq", sequenceName = "pagine_id_seq")
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private long id;

@Column(name = "titolo", nullable = false, length = 60, unique = true)
private String titolo;

@Column(name = "slug", nullable = false, length = 60, unique = true)
private String slug;

@Column(name = "contenuto", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String contenuto;

@Column(name = "data_creazione", nullable = false)
private Date dataCreazione;

@Column(name = "data_modifica")
private Date dataModifica;

@Column(name = "stato", nullable = false)
private String stato;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "utente_id", nullable = false)
private Users user;

getter and setter...
....
}
```

Tank You
Lorenzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a special case in tapestry when your page class has the name `Index` it will not include the page name in the URL. So if you rename the class `Page` to `Index` I think you'll achieve what you want without requiring any explicit url rewriting

Comment: Tank you Lance this is every simple solutions and it worked perfectly